# Is there a way to recompose messages from command line?

Tags: ros, topic-tools, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a tool that can take a complex message from one topic, then compose a new message from some of its fields and publish it on another topic?

For instance, [JTCartesianController](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesian%20Controller) exposes rather complex [state](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/robot_mechanism_controllers/html/msg/JTCartesianControllerState.html), where I need only `state/x` field of type `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped`. So such magic tool should do something like:

```
$ rosmagic /jt_cart_controller/state/x /robot_pose
```

`rostopic` is able to `echo` 'subtopics', but there is no way to republish them.

`topic_tools relay` does not work with subtopics either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58995/is-there-a-way-to-recompose-messages-from-command-line?/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the approach of writing echo "rostopic echo" output to yaml file, optionally changing it and republishing using "rostopic pub" to be fast and work very well. See the "YAML data file" section of the [rostopic pub](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_pub) documentation. You can easily change data or also cut/paste submessages out of a composed message and republish them this way.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-23**:
Thanks! It also works fine with the pipes, i.e. I can simply do `rostopic echo /eef_pose/pose/position | rostopic pub /xyz_position geometry_msgs/Vector3`. However I was unable to find any generic command-line tools for parsing YAML, so looks like the scripting is unavoidable...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](https://github.com/bgromov/brl_tools) is my first attempt on Python code.

The `recompose.py` script allows to take a message of any(?) complexity and generate another message based on given format. The format of new message is specified by YAML string, where the values of elements are the paths (delimited by `/`) to a data in input message.

The most valuable use case for myself is to take a complex message like [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/gazebo_msgs/html/msg/ContactsState.html) and combine [geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/WrenchStamped.html). Main problem here is that we need both `std_msgs/Header` and `geometry_msgs/Wrench` to be combined in a new message. However these fields are spread across the `ContactsState`.

So, this issue can be solve with the provided script as follows:

```
rostopic echo /gazebo_bumper | recompose.py "{header: header, wrench: 'states[0]/total_wrench'}"
```

Maybe I'm reinventing the wheel, but I was unable to find a ready to use solution so far.

Hope it can be useful for others.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3